# Investigating Tripwire report - 172 files added to "/proc/sys/net/"

Tags: tripwire

Tripwire reported 172 files added to various sub-folders at "/proc/sys/net/ipv4" and "/proc/sys/net/ipv6".

How can i investigate this?

I'm running an Ubuntu 14 vps.

Answer (score 3):

Ignore them and tell tripwire to ignore /proc and /sys

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your answer is in line with other info found on the web. It seems it can be safely ignored. I wonder why this only occurred now, several months after having tripwire monitoring the system.

Comment: Possibly a kernel module got loaded which added some virtual files there?